# Aggregating interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I've got this class:

```
class UrlManagementServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IUrlManagementService>, IUrlManagementService
```

ClientBase implements `IDisposable` and `ICommunicationObject`. I've also got this interface:

```
interface IUrlManagementProxy : IUrlManagementService, ICommunicationObject, IDisposable
```

But I can't cast `UrlManagementServiceClient` objects to `IUrlManagementProxy`. Is there some way to accomplish this? I want to end up with an object that can access all the methods on all three interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only cast to interfaces that you inherit from, to be able to cast to `IUrlManagementProxy` you need to implement that interface.

```
class UrlManagementServiceClient :
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IUrlManagementService>, IUrlManagementProxy
```

You can then cast `UrlManagementServiceClient` to either `UrlManagementProxy`, `IUrlManagementService`, `ICommunicationObject` or `IDisposable`.

**Edit**
The WCF-generated classes are partial, that means that you can extend the class definition in another file. Put

```
public partial class UrlManagementServiceClient : IUrlManagementProxy {}
```

in another code file and your class will implement your full `IUrlManagementProxy` interface too and you can then cast it to `IUrlManagementProxy`.

Comment: UrlManagementServiceClient is an auto-generated WCF client. I'd like to avoid manual edits to the file in case it needs to be re-generated.

Comment: @RandomEngy, You can add a partial class definition with your own interface in a separate file, see edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make `UrlManagementServiceClient` implement `IUrlManagementProxy` instead of `IUrlManagementService`

```
class UrlManagementServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IUrlManagementProxy>, IUrlManagementProxy
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IUrlManagementProxy` on `UrlManagementServiceClient`. There's no other way — it's a **separate** type.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously cannot cast an object to an interface which it doesn't implement.

But, what you can do (if it makes sense to implement all methods for each of those interfaces out of an `UrlManagementServiceClient` instance), is to **wrap** your `UrlManagementServiceClient` in an object which implements the interfaces you need.

This is called the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) (rather than proxy). A proxy usually "appears" to be the underlying object, while in this case you are adding functionality which your client doesn't have.

In other words, you would need a new class:

```
public class UrlManagementClientProxy : IUrlManagementProxy 
{
     // we need a reference to the underlying client
     private readonly UrlManagementServiceClient _client;

     // underlying client is passed to the proxy in constructor
     public UrlManagementClientProxy(UrlManagementServiceClient client)
     {
         _client = client;
     }

     #region IUrlManagementProxy methods

     // you implementation goes here. if the underlying client
     // already implements a certain method, then you just need
     // to pass the call 

     // for example, client already implements methods
     // from the IUrlManagementService interface, so use them

     public string GetUrl() // made up
     {
          return _client.GetUrl();
     }

     #endregion
}
```

This allows you to reuse client's implementation, and add additional functionality on top of it.

Comment: Tried this but there's a whole lot of stuff to implement on ICommunicationObject and IUrlManagementService and it was getting messy. I went with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I just extended the class and declared the aggregate interface on it:

```
public class UrlManagementProxy : UrlManagementServiceClient, IUrlManagementProxy
{
    public UrlManagementProxy(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
        : base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I use `UrlManagementProxy` instead of `UrlManagementServiceClient`.

I only need to pass through constructors that I need. All the rest is handled automatically. Also this way I don't need to modify the `UrlManagementServiceClient` so I can re-generate it and everything will still work.